# How much can one rely on the mean or median to infer a difference?

Tags: data-visualization, mean, median, exploratory-data-analysis

When performing an explonatory data analysis, one tries to visualize patterns of behavior of your target variable against the variables that you're assuming could explain the target variable. For example, consider that you're objective is to assess if the status of the loan could be explained by the income of the person. One could visualize this relationship through a boxplot as the following image shows

[image]

In this example, one see that there is a slight difference in the annual income for the people that fully paid their loans based on the median. Thus, when peforming a visual exploratory analysis how much can one rely on measures like the median or the mean to conclude that there is in fact a difference in the groups of interest? In this case, **how valid would be to affirm that there is indeed a difference based on the mean**. Alternatively, one could take an statistical approach to test if there is an difference in mean among groups through a t-test or ANOVA.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, that is what statistics is all about.  You need to do the formal hypothesis testing, as you could receive curve-balls when it comes to interpreting the median, mean - or mode - by eye.

This looks like a great pattern for regression or ANOVA.

I am reminded of the old statistics joke (one of the few): 9 bankrupt people are in a bar drowning their sorrows.  A billionaire drops in and, presto! the average wealth is now $100 million each!  Here the mean tells you nothing....